# how to collect the data from database in array and then put that data for each row of table view in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to collect the data from database in the array and then after put that in each cell of the table view.

i dont know how to retrieve the data in array for select * from tablename for single row.

Comment: CoreData or raw SQLite3 statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about a Core Data database, doing [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) from developer.apple.com should give you an idea of how to do it.

Sam